# Yii2 store cookies in different format

Tags: cookies, yii2

I am setting cookie on server side using yii2's cookie class with the code below, but when I get it on client side with javascript it prints in different format like `3ab2e6b31664352c0398b57bd98720da925d1254d476f4d7c4e7c29ce71c0c14a:2:{i:0;s:3:"uid";i:1;i:1;}` what is the reason and  what is the proper way of getting value of uid?

```
            $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
            if (!$cookies->has('uid')){
                $cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
                    'name' => 'uid',
                    'value' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id,
                    'httpOnly' => false,
                ]));                
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done for the cookie validation, which protects cookies from being modified on the client side.

Your string is a serialized `Cookie` object, signed with [yii\web\Request::$cookieValidationKey}(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$cookieValidationKey-detail) using [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) PHP function.

The detailed explanation you can find in the [Guide - Sessions and Cookies](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookie-validation).

It's strongly recommended not to turn off the cookie validation. If you still want to use the unsigned cookie, set it manually using [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function. Please notice, it will be unavailable in `Yii::$app->request->cookie` and you should access it though `$_COOKIE`